# How do I change the background in my WordPress Theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I use the following theme for WordPress

http://wordpressthemes.mifdesign.com/themeviewer/index.php?wptheme=Deep+Silent

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/deep-silent

I want to change the background which I did but it still shows a red border all around (see picture http://imageshack.us/f/710/wordpressg.png/). Where do I delete the frame? Can not find it. Would also like to do the framing / page wider. Seems like I have to change several times in my css or where do I change it?

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic for SO, and would be better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @shanethehat I partially agree and partially disagree. The question is related to wordpress, but the problem is a general coding problem and not restricted to wordpress/wordpress knowledge. So, in my opinion it fits both sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove whole red part from page than remove following lines from your css

```
body{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #850000;}

#page-top {background-image: url("images/bg_page_top.png");}

#navmenu-bg {background-image: url("images/bg_page.png");}

#content, #header { background-image: url("images/bg_page.png");}

#footer {background-image: url("images/bg_footer.png");}
```